# Cannot Create Folder on Sharepoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, document-library

I am trying to write some code that will create a folder in a sharepoint document library. I have the following code:

```
        vmProjectFileList projectFileList = new vmProjectFileList();
        AuthenticationConfiguration config = AuthenticationConfiguration.ReadFromJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        string siteURL = config.SiteUrl;
        string[] scopes = new string[] { config.Scope };
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = AuthenticationConfiguration.Result();
        Web WebSite = Sharepoint.GetSharepointWeb(siteURL, authenticationResult).Result;
        var ListItem = Sharepoint.SharepointCreateNewFolder(siteURL, authenticationResult, "Project Files", "This is a test");

public static ListItem SharepointCreateNewFolder(string Uri, AuthenticationResult authResult, string DocumentLibrary, string ProjectTitle)
    {
        try
        {
            ListItem newFolder = null;
            using (var clientContext = ContextHelper.GetClientContext(Uri, authResult.AccessToken))
            {

                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                List DocumentLibraryFolder = web.Lists.GetByTitle(DocumentLibrary);
                var folderCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation()
                {
                    UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder,
                    LeafName = ProjectTitle
                };
                newFolder = DocumentLibraryFolder.AddItem(folderCreateInfo);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
            return newFolder;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

It should create a folder called "this is a test", but the  code executes, doesn't give an error, but does not create the folder.

Not sure what I am missing. I can bring up a list of files, but I cannot create a folder programmatically.

I am using Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client and Microsoft.Identity.Client.

Regards,
Darren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `newFolder.Update()` line before `ctx.ExecuteQuery`. Try below code. It should work:

```
public static ListItem SharepointCreateNewFolder(string Uri, AuthenticationResult authResult, string DocumentLibrary, string ProjectTitle)
    {
        try
        {
            ListItem newFolder = null;
            using (var clientContext = ContextHelper.GetClientContext(Uri, authResult.AccessToken))
            {

                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                List DocumentLibraryFolder = web.Lists.GetByTitle(DocumentLibrary);
                var folderCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation()
                {
                    UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder,
                    LeafName = ProjectTitle
                };
                newFolder = DocumentLibraryFolder.AddItem(folderCreateInfo);
                newFolder.Update();
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
            return newFolder;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```